# Query: remove 1 feature from list of features and PBIs under an epic

Tags: tfs

I'm trying to build a query that lists all Features and PBIs under an EPIC but eliminate several of the Features that don't apply to me. I can't seem to find a way.

Assume

[image: Sample Structure]

I need a query that will result in the following

[image: Desired Results]

So basically my desired results would be to remove Features 2 & 6 (and all PBIs under them). Since the Title field seems to be shared across Epics, Features, PBIs, etc, I can't figure out a way to remove a couple of features by their titles. I've also tried to remove them by using a <> ID number.

Comment: What is YOUR effort? ... we are not a code writing service.

Answer (score 0):

Your requirement can not be achieved by a Tree query. You could save your query and open it in Excel to filter it as the screenshot below shows:

[image]